# How to delete CollectionView cell with button according to JSON parameter value in swift

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview

I am unable to delete CollectionView cell according to JSON parameter value.. i am getting correct `pic_id` value.. but if i delete that cell here always collectionview first cell is deleted...

**If i delete any cell its always deleting from first to last**

**JSON request:**

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"params": {
   "pic_id": "84"
}
}
```

**JSON response:**

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "status": {
        "code": "-36739",
        "message": "Success",
        "meaning": "Images deleted Successfully"
    }
}
}
```

code: **with the below code.. collectionview cells are adding in order.. but if i delete last cell its always deleted first cell**.. where am i wrong.. please do help with code

```
extension EditProfileImageViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrImageItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.imgView.image = arrImageItems[indexPath.item].profileImage
    cell.lblTitle.text = arrImageItems[indexPath.row].title
    cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteService(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
@objc func deleteService(sender:UIButton) {
    
    let picId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pic_id")
    
    print("selected picid \(picId)")
        let param = ["pic_id" : picId]
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param as [String : Any], method: .post, loaderNeed: false, loadingButton: sender as! TransitionButton, needViewHideShowAfterLoading: nil, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.edit_profile_images_remove, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false, actionErrorOrSuccess: nil, fromLoginPageCallBack: nil) { [weak self] (resp) in
            if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
                print("total result: \(code)")
                let success = code["status"] as? [String : Any]
                let message = success?["message"] as? String
                if message == "Success"{
                   
                    let i = sender.tag
                    self?.arrImageItems.remove(at: i)
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()                    }
            }else{
                self?.view.makeToast(CommonMessages.somethingWentWrong)
            }
        }
}
```

i need to delete selected `pic_id` cell.. but its always deleting the first cell.. please do help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use `tag` on this situations. You can add tag to your button which tag value is `indexPath.row` in `cellForItemAt` like :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
cell.imgView.image = arrImageItems[indexPath.item].profileImage
cell.lblTitle.text = arrImageItems[indexPath.row].title
cell.deleteButton.tag = indexpath.row // added line
cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteService(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

return cell
```

}
Then in `deleteService` function u can reach index

```
@objc func deleteService(sender:UIButton) { 
   let selectedIndex = sender.tag
 ......

}
```

> NOTE

you use `let i = sender.tag` but in cell you didn't give a tag your button so `sender.tag` is gonna be `0` by default.This is why first element of array is deleted always.

Comment: offcourse this is unrelated to this question.... but got bug

with the above my code i am able to delete only one cell.. maybe in userdefaults its saving only one value... if so how to delete number of selected buttons .. pls help me here

Comment: You can create an empty array then add indexes which selected . Then you can remove this indexes

Comment: can u answer here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916969/how-to-delete-every-selected-cell-of-collectionview-with-button-in-swift